# How to configure Webpack with link tag in HtmlWebpackPlugin template file?

Tags: webpack, stylesheet

I'm trying to setup a basic webpack config.
I use HtmlWebpackPlugin and set template file like this (index.html and style.css are in the same directory):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head> 
<body>
</body>    
</html>
```

Everything was fine till I set link tag because I got this error message:

***Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.***

I was googling a lot, tried a lot of things, but I can not resolve this very-very simple problem.
I think it is not possible :(

Am I right? Or what should I do?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You must provide the correct path to style.css something like `"../sources/style.css"`
A better solution is to use the mini-css-extract-plugin and place styles directly in js but that's another story;)

Comment: I set the correct path to style.css. Both files are in the same directory. At first time, I wanted to try out the simplest style injection, not import from js.

Comment: Show project structure and webpack configuration will be easier than guessing :)

Comment: Atteched screenshots...

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, there is a wrong path to style.css if you change to `../src/style.css` should work but there will be a problem if you have a production version. Unfortunately, but the webpack works the best way is to import the css file into js - `import './style.css';` and using mini-css-extract-plugin. Take a look at my solution [style-resources-loader](https://github.com/tomik23/webpack-babel-corejs/tree/style-resources-loader) you also have a more extensive example [webpack-boilerplate](https://github.com/tomik23/webpack-boilerplate)

Comment: I'm about to explode... you were right!! Thanks.
Next step is to import (s)css, I just wanted to solve this basic task.